# Maria DB cluster setting issue in centos 7

Tags: mariadb

I am failed to configure galera cluster in centos 7.
Here I did following steps as mentaion by this https://mariadb.com/resources/blog/getting-started-with-mariadb-galera-and-mariadb-maxscale-on-centos/.
Here is my OS detail : [root@localhost my.cnf.d]# cat /etc/redhat-release
CentOS Linux release 7.4.1708 (Core)
Make follwoing change in server.cnf file as mentaioned in the link.
After issuing  the galera_new_cluster command , still I could see cluster not yet start.
Also surpriseing I could see that any change in server.cnf file does not effect in maria db, if If I write juck data , still after issuing galera_new_cluster, maria db started , and  status is look like
ariaDB [(none)]>  show global status like 'wsrep%' ;

```
+--------------------------+----------------------+
| Variable_name            | Value                |
+--------------------------+----------------------+
| wsrep_cluster_conf_id    | 18446744073709551615 |
| wsrep_cluster_size       | 0                    |
| wsrep_cluster_state_uuid |                      |
| wsrep_cluster_status     | Disconnected         |
| wsrep_connected          | OFF                  |
| wsrep_local_bf_aborts    | 0                    |
| wsrep_local_index        | 18446744073709551615 |
| wsrep_provider_name      |                      |
| wsrep_provider_vendor    |                      |
| wsrep_provider_version   |                      |
| wsrep_ready              | OFF                  |
| wsrep_thread_count       | 0                    |
+--------------------------+----------------------+
```

Comment: Here is my galera change settinmg

Comment: [galera]
# Mandatory settings
wsrep_on=ON
wsrep_provider=/usr/lib64/galera/libgalera_smm.so
wsrep_cluster_address=gcomm://192.168.56.114,192.168.56.113,192.168.56.112
binlog_format=row
default_storage_engine=InnoDB
innodb_autoinc_lock_mode=2

Comment: It look like maridb deamon did not point to /etc/my.cnf.d/server.cnf . I reinstall several time and clean up all folder but same happen

Answer (score 0):

check you file /etc/my.cnf
it should be like that:

```
 #
 # This group is read both both by the client and the server
 # use it for options that affect everything
 # [client-server]

 #
 # include all files from the config directory

 includedir /etc/my.cnf.d
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me after reinstalling only to find out the /etc/my.cnf.d/ is not referenced, I instead added the galera config in the my.cnf and it worked
sample my.cnf:

```
 #
 [galera]
 binlog_format=row
 default-storage-engine=InnoDB

 innodb_autoinc_lock_mode=2

 bind-address=0.0.0.0

 wsrep_on=ON

 wsrep_provider=/usr/lib64/galera/libgalera_smm.so

 wsrep_cluster_address="gcomm://172.16.1.2,172.16.1.3” # include all of the master node ips



 ## Galera Cluster Configuration

 wsrep_cluster_name=“test_cluster”



 ## Galera Synchronization Configuration

 wsrep_sst_method=rsync



 ## Galera Node Configuration

 wsrep_node_address=“172.16.1.3” 
 wsrep_node_name=“node-0”
 #
```